# How to pass dynamic connectionstring with username and password directly in SSRS using C#?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2

I am using **SSRS** for reporting purpose in my application.In SSRS i am using **Embedded DataSource** for fetching data.

I want to **pass dynamic connection string in c# code** to that datasource so based on connection string parameter it will fetch data assordingly.

Is that possible ?

Answer (score 0):

> //Here you can fetch Database Name dynamically and assign to Initial
>   Catalog for  preparing dynamic connection string.

```
string conStr = @"Data Source=DILIPPC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Student";

// Fetch all datasources
 var dataSources = this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.GetDataSources();
 List<DataSourceCredentials> credentials = new List<DataSourceCredentials();
 foreach (var dataSource in dataSources)
 {
    DataSourceCredentials credential = new DataSourceCredentials();
                  credential.Name = dataSource.Name;
                  credential.UserId = " "; // Wirte username of your connection
                  credential.Password = " "; // Wirte password of your connection
                  credentials.Add(credential);
 }
 this.reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetDataSourceCredentials(credentials);

 // Added ConStr parameter and pass this parameter to SSRS report.
ReportParameter rptPar = new ReportParameter("ConStr", conStr);
reportViewer1.ServerReport.SetParameters(rptPar);
```